# Why the selenium+python code can run line by line in terminal instead of in a whole file format?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
import time,os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

target = "https://pan.baidu.com/"
driver.get(target)
name='name'
passwd='passwd'
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="account-title"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="TANGRAM__PSP_4__userName"]').send_keys(name)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="TANGRAM__PSP_4__password"]').send_keys(passwd)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="TANGRAM__PSP_4__submit"]').click()

try:
    path1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="test1"]')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(path1).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).context_click(path1).perform()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="context-menu"]/ul/li[21]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="g-button g-button-blue-large"]/span/span').click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    pass

try:
    path2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="test2"]')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(path2).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).context_click(path2).perform()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="context-menu"]/ul/li[21]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="g-button g-button-blue-large"]/span/span').click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    pass
```

The above code snippet run successfully line by line in python3 terminal,
to input several lines everytime into python3 terminal,do three task for me.
1.automatically login to pan.baidu.com
2.to delete file named `test1`
3.to delete file named `test2`

Then to save the above code snippet as up.py and run it with `time python3 up.py`.

A very interesting thing happen.
1.running time

```
time  python3  up.py    
real    0m4.231s
user    0m0.192s
sys 0m0.080s
```

Why the running time is less then 20 seconds?

2.the third task haven't done
The file named `test2` still there ,not deleted by program.

How to explain the strange issues and fix it?

Comment: It seem that the first `try/except` block brakes on `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="context-menu"]/ul/li[21]').click()` as this element cannot be fount (generated dynamically?) and the second might brake on `path2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="test2"]')` so all of your `time.sleep(5)` lines are skipped. Try your code without `try/except` construction and check the exception

Comment: Both  'test1' and 'test2' are in pan.baidu.com ,you can give a try.

Answer (score 0):

To add a important line:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Comment: Since this is an answer, perhaps you could edit it to explain _why_ and _how_ it solved your problem? Great news that you've figured it out!